# Dismissing modal view controller shows black screen in ( iOS13.5 Xcode 11.5)

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

```
let cropViewController = CropViewController(image: images[0])
cropViewController.delegate = self

self.present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Dismissing this view controller from a delegate method , shows a black screen

```
func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController,
                        didCropToImage image: UIImage,
                        withRect cropRect: CGRect,
                        angle: Int) {
    // 'image' is the newly cropped version of the original image
    cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        self.setImageAndReloadRow(image: image)
    })

}
```

Xcode 11.5 and iOS13.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also same issue after selecting image and cropped,only black screen was appearing.

Replace

```
cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil).
```

With

```
let viewController = cropViewController.children.first! 
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical 
viewController.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```